# Connectors on Device prototyping

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, button, ffc

I´m drawing my own PCB and I´m searching for components to use for this purpose.
Since I´m not an expert in this fields, I have some unsolved questions:

- (I´m using Eagle Cadsoft) I need to create a custom library for each component that I will use on my PCB? Is there any website where I can find Eagle Libraries and buy the same components?
- I would like to use a Power button on the side but the board will be parallel to the button so I was searching for a Button with flat connector. Is there any specific name to call those tactile button (Similar to power button on smartphone)?
- I will use some flat connector as FFC cable , how it works the comunication of between microcontroller and unit connected through ffc connector? May I define a particoular communication protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of places on the internet where you can find pre-made libraries:

http://www.element14.com/community/community/cadsoft_eagle/eagle_cad_libraries
https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Eagle-Library
http://www.we-online.com/web/en/electronic_components/toolbox_pbs/Eagle_eiCan.php

I simply googled "Eagle Libraries" and got the above as the top four hits.

Generally, I recommend making your own custom libraries for consistency sake, but that's just my own personal preference.

Some of the parts you describe are far too specific and will probably not be found in a pre-made library. You'll need to select the part using Digikey or Mouser and view the datasheet. Use the information in the datasheet to create the component in a custom library.

Your wording of your last question is not clear. It does not seem to have anything to do with Eagle or PCB design, but rather the software on the microcontroller itself, which should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Glad to help. If you're completely satisfied, consider selecting it as the accepted answer. Thank you =)